# Stanton Parish's Plan

Tags: alphas

In the series Alphas, 
Stanton Parish's endgame is the photostims across the US which kill normal ordinary people but increase the ability of the Alphas. My question is why does Stanton Parish only plant them in the US? Why not around the world? He had enough resources to plant them around the world because he was involved in exporting and importing pieces from China. So why was his plan not global??

Answer (score 6):

**Parish did not distribute more of the photostimulators around the world for one reason: Control. Activating Alphan metahuman potential around the world without leadership could have only led to anarchy and rivalry among such beings. He did not want that, he wanted to control and lead such individuals in a bid for power.**

Like any good soldier, Stanton Parish's plan required the development of infrastructure as well as a quality command structure. His goal may have been worldwide conquest, but he would have to defeat opposing Alphans, other governments, and potentially operatives of those governments. He wanted to have a nearly unstoppable plan in place before undertaking such a goal.

- He had worked for quite some time to develop financial resources, a local metahuman support group and an awareness of opposing forces. He had already begun laying connections in government and staking out metahuman resources including freeing already captured metahumans from prison.
- His process was to infiltrate an area, learn where the Alphans were, find out whether he can manipulate them, kill potential dissenters, absorb more tractable members, move on and repeat. Each addition lends fantastic abilities to his army, so slow growth is simply a more effective strategy.
- Since the capacity of his Alphan army varied widely, it made sense he would only expand it slowly, to better utilize their capacities and to better manipulate the users of said powers for his purposes. He wanted them to be under his control and guidance.
- Since he was already embroiled in a struggle against the United States security services, he didn't want to empower anyone who was not already under his control. If he were to empower a significant number of said metahumans without them having an allegiance to him, he would be creating other potential challengers, not supporters.